# Getting "model is not associated with other Model" in sequelize when using belongsToMany

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many, sequelize.js

I am using `sequelize` with `postgreSQL`. I have two schemas namely `User` and `Location`. A `User` can have many `Locations` and a `Location` can have many `Users`.

My `User` Schema is as follows

```
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        require: true
    },
    middleName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        require: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        require: true
    },
    age: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        require: false
    },
    email_Id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        require: true,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    }
```

My `Location` Schema is as follows:

```
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    latitude: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
        require: true
    },
    longitude: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
        require: true
    },
    locationAddress: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    mailBoxNo: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    }
```

I Am using `belongsToMany` of `sequelize` and creating a third table name `UserLocation` where I have mentioned `belongsToMany` for both `User` and `Location` which is as below:

```
User.belongsToMany(Location, {
    through: 'UserLocation'
});
Location.belongsToMany(User, {
    through: 'UserLocation'
});
```

My requirement is to get all the `locations` for a given `user` id. My Code is as follows:

```
    var param = req.body;
    var options = {};
    if (param.where) {
        options.where = param.where;
    }
    options.include = [{
        model: User  //User Model
    }, {
        model: Location  //Location Model
    }];

    //Here userLocation refers to UserLocation Schema
    userLocation.findAll(options).then(function (response) {
             //Some Logic
        }).catch(function (err) {
            //Error handling
        });
```

While executing the above code, I getting the following error:

> User Model is not associated with UserLocation Model.

I am unable to understand why I am getting the following error. Can somebody help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this for getting all the locations of a given user;

```
User
  .findOne({
    "where": {
      "id": param.where
    },
    "include": [Location]
  })
  .then(function(user) {
    // should get this user
    console.log(user);

    // should get all locations of this user
    console.log(user.Locations);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // error handling
  });
```